# Getting duplicate homepage links | Even if there is only one page in Dashboard Please Help

Tags: links

[image: Wordpress page navbar links]

I recently imported a old wordpress site into a new site everything ok but the NAVIGATION links are showing home (10 times duplicate links) see below picture 
Please can u answer how to solve this

I can only one entry in dashboard
my wordpress link : http://digitalspacetv.in/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the menu you see in the dashboard is actually assigned to the main menu area of the Theme.

Under `Appearance > Menus` At the top, under `Edit Menus`, check `Select a menu to edit:`.

Are there any menus? If so, scroll to the bottom to see `Menu Settings`. Make sure you check the box for the main menu area in your theme. It can be named differently depending on the them.

[image]

If you do not see any menus in the , `Select a menu to edit:` section at the top. Simply `Create New`. When you are done creating your new menu, scroll to the bottom of the edit page and assign it to the main menu area in `Menu Settings`.

You may also find it helpful to simply delete any extra pages under the `Pages` section of the WP Dashboard. By default, if no menu is assigned, WP will show all the pages. That may be what you are experiencing.